# Is there an automatic compiler for HAML (Windows-based)?

Tags: haml

Is there an automatic compiler for HAML files which will generate HTML files upon saving the HAML file? Basically, I'm looking for a HAML equivalent of [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless), which is an automatic compiler for LESS - if you look at their website you'll quickly get an idea of what I'm asking for.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649398/how-can-i-auto-compile-my-haml-files-into-html-files-in-a-tiny-project-that-does